# Make script load faster than html content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, download

I'm creating a splash page using canvas and javascript that includes an "erasable" layer on top of HTML. The erasable canvas layer completely covers the html content in the background, and it is not to be visible until the user starts erasing.

However, upon loading, the html content shows up first and then the erasable layer appears. Is there a way for the erasable canvas layer to show up first without the user seeing the html content until erased?

I tried putting the erasable canvas and the script used by it before the HTML content, and it still does not work.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap all your html content within a hidden div and show it after the canvas has loaded. Place the canvas outside of the wrapped html.

Answer (score 2):

You could try making all your HTML content hidden and then with your JavaScript code make it visible when needed.

Comment: This, in your code add `<body style="display:none">` and then once the jQuery is loaded call `$('body').show();`

Comment: @Joshua The _erasable canvas_ would be placed inside the body so to hide it wouldn't work. Instead one might wrap all the non-canvas code in a `div` and apply your solution to that.

Comment: Fair point, my mind just went straight to the "nuclear solution".

Answer (score 0):

What looks like your problem is that your script is loaded before your HTML is being parsed. You could have several options like:

1) Have your JavaScript create your HTML content but also make sure it creates the erasable canvas first. You could do this several ways or even use XMLHttpRequest() to go fetch the HTML content.

2) As mentioned by @Beans, you can have something like this:

```
<script>
document.body.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // your canvas code here (make sure it get displayed on top of body)
    document.body.style.display = null;
});
</script>
<body style="display: none">
Some stuff here
</body>
```